# importing of existing android project ia being imported with name MainActivity

Tags: android, import, workspace

whenever I try to import an existing android project it is imported with the name as "Main Activity"
Hence due to this I cannot import more than 1 project as the first project that i would have imported was with the name "Main Activity", Due to this to import another project I have to delete the existing project with the name "Main Activity".
I have even tried to switch work space but the problem still persists.

Comment: you could refactor->rename your existing project named MainActivity in your workspace and then start the import again.

Comment: Yup, this could be.But isn't there any permanent solution except installing a fresh ADT.

Comment: frankly no a lot of developers use names like mainactivity,library and main as the project and folder name. So even after updating you are likely to run into this issue

Comment: Actually, neither the name of the project nor the folder name is "Main Activity". But when it is imported it gets changed to "Main Activity".